# python get time stamp on file in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get the datestamp on the file in mm/dd/yyyy format

```
time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
```

gives me detailed time stamp `Fri Jun 07 16:54:31 2013`

How can I display the output as `06/07/2013`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You want to use [`time.strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) to format the timestamp; convert it to a time tuple first using either [`time.gmtime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) or [`time.localtime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime):

```
time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import getmtime

datetime.fromtimestamp(getmtime(file)).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create the datetime object using the **ctime str** like you mention and then format it back to a string of any format.

```
str1 = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)) # Fri Jun 07 16:54:31 2013
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(str1, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
datetime_object.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # 06/07/2013
```

This way you don't have to deal with timezones + absolute timestamp from the Epoch

Credit: [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Linking: [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

http://strftime.org/