# python get time stamp on file in mm/dd/yyyy-HH:MM format

Tags: python, date, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get the datestamp on the file in mm-dd-yyyy-hh:mm format.

```
time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
```

gives me detailed time stamp:

```
Fri Jun 07 16:54:31 2013
```

How can I display the output as:

```
06-07-2013-16:54
```

This is very similar to:
[python get time stamp on file in mm/dd/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994696/python-get-time-stamp-on-file-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

This is doing the half of what I want but I can't add hour and minute.

```
time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found it, I needed to add %H:%M like below:

```
time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime())
```